# Design of active or passive class domain

Tags: domain-driven-design

Sorry if my (simplified) example is too broad.

Given this model (written in C#):

```
class Ball
{
}
```

Let's assume that a ball can be launched.

To implement this feature, I can define something like:

```
class Ball
{
    void Launch();
}
```

or something like:

```
class BallLauncher
{
    void Launch(Ball ball);
}
```

In which situations is better use first approach and which the second one?

In fact, this example tries to simplify an actual real underlying model. In that model, I need to upload files (`Package`) to a repository.

Then, I don't know if the repository should upload (physical copy) a package (files) to itself or it is the package who should upload itself to a repository.

Comment: Deciding which responsibility goes to which class is extremely broad topic. Answers to such simple and contrived example are never going to be helpful in real world.

Comment: @Euphoric: especially since the actual problem the OP tries to solve is much more complicated (see his comment to my answer). Do you believe the question should be edited? Also, I tried to provide a detailed answer, but as you say, the topic is extremely broad; do you think there are other relevant things to add to the answer (especially for future readers)? Would it help if I switch to community wiki?

Comment: I agree with you that is too broad, but is a problem that I found frequently when I figure out how can I design the domain logic. I just update the question to reflect comments that I wrote into @MainMa answer, in order to clarify the concrete problem that I'm having actually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Basic example: launch a ball

Analyzing business logic helps. Can the ball possibly launch itself? Probably not. It's just a ball, and can't move by itself. This means that you'll create a `BallLauncher` in order to launch it.

What would `Ball` class contain? Mostly properties of the object, such as radius, color and texture.

### Two objects example: launch a rocket

**A `Rocket` may be launched itself, or may require a launcher.** Sometimes, looking at the logic, it may not be obvious where to put the method. A rocket is not passive, but may need a launcher. A launcher is required to launch a rocket, but the rocket participates in the launching as well.

When the logic is not obvious, here's a hint: implement the `Launch` method and watch how `Rocket` and `Launcher` are used.

Example:

```cs
class Rocket
{
    public void Launch()
    {
        this.ControlTower.RequestTakeoff().WhenAuthorized(launcher =>
        {
            launcher.Prepare();
            if (launcher.Status == LauncherStatus.ReadyForLaunch)
            {
                launcher.Launch();
                launcher.PrepareNewRocket();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new BrokenLauncherException();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

over-relies on `Launcher` and should be moved to `Launcher` class. On the other hand:

```cs
class Launcher
{
    public void Launch(Rocket rocket)
    {
        rocket.Ignite();
        rocket.IncreasePressureTo(Rocket.RecommendedPressureOnLaunch);
        rocket.PrepareForTakeoff();
        if (rocket.IsReady)
        {
            this.Release();
            rocket.Takeoff();
        }
        else
        {
            rocket.CancelTakeoff();
            rocket.Engines.ShutDownEmergency();
            throw new BrokenRocketException();
        }
    }
}
```

is illustrative of a method which finds itself in a wrong class: it should be moved to `Rocket`.

### Three objects example: package, repository, uploader

In the same way, if you have a `Package` and a `Repository`:

- Should the package be uploaded to a repository,
- Should a repository upload a package to itself,
- Or should there be an `Uploader` which deals with packages and repositories through `Upload(package, repository)`?

Again, business logic prevails, and as in the previous example, watching how `Package` and `Repository` are used inside the method may help.

- If `Upload` over-relies on `Package`, this may be a hint that it should be `Package.Upload`.
- If `Upload` calls the methods from `Repository` practically all the time, move it to `Repository`.
- If `Upload` has a logic which simply doesn't fit in `Package` or `Repository`, this is a good opportunity for creating an `Uploader`.

Comment: In fact, my example tries to simplify the real underlying model, that upload files as `Package` to a repository. The repository may upload a file collection to itself or package must upload itself to a repository?

Answer (score 1):

From an OO perspective, if `Launch()` implies mutating the Ball's internal state, I would tend to prefer the first design.

One good practice in OO is the [Tell, Don't Ask principle](http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask) :

> you should endeavor to tell objects what you want them to do; do not
>   ask them questions about their state, make a decision, and then tell
>   them what to do

Chances are that `Launch(Ball ball)` will ask stuff from the Ball and then act based on this, changing its state, while `Ball.Launch()` will keep everything nicely encapsulated in it.

The case where I see a `Launch(Ball ball)` signature making sense is if you want to delegate the instantiation of a Ball to external code and then inject that Ball into the Launcher as a method-wide dependency. But the Launcher would still probably need to call something like `Ball.Launch()` anyway.